# Including the Table Column with name but getting an error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Include the Table Column with name but getting an error `Scrupt out of Range` I do not know why. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim userSelectedDate As Date
    Dim DateRange As Range
    
    DateRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("T_EMP").ListColumns("[START DATE]").DataBodyRange
            
    'Show calendar form if selected cell falls within "DateRange" named range
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Sheet2.Range("DateRange")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsDate(ActiveCell.value) Then userSelectedDate = ActiveCell.value
    
        'Call CalendarForm
        userSelectedDate = CalendarForm.GetDate(SelectedDate:=userSelectedDate)
            
        'Make sure user selected a valid date from the CalendarForm
        If userSelectedDate <> 0 Then ActiveCell.value = userSelectedDate
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing `Set`, and does the column name actually contain brackets `[...]`? Also you should be using `Target`, not `ActiveCell`, and `Me`, not `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thank you but when i use set now. It gives me an error ` Object Variable or with block variable not set`. Yes it caontains brracket i get that using `= in cell` Can you please post an answer. that what it should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're missing `Set`: `Set DateRange = ...`.
- Variables don't belong inside quotes, and you already have a `Range` variable: `DateRange`, not `Sheet2.Range("DateRange")`
- Use `Target` and `Me` in place of `ActiveCell` and `ActiveSheet`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' only proceed if one cell selected

    Dim userSelectedDate As Date
    Dim DateRange As Range
    
    Set DateRange = Me.ListObjects("T_EMP").ListColumns("[START DATE]").DataBodyRange
            
    'Show calendar form if selected cell falls within "DateRange" named range
    If Not Intersect(Target, DateRange) Is Nothing Then
        If IsDate(Target.Value) Then userSelectedDate = Target.Value
    
        'Call CalendarForm
        userSelectedDate = CalendarForm.GetDate(SelectedDate:=userSelectedDate)
            
        'Make sure user selected a valid date from the CalendarForm
        If userSelectedDate <> 0 Then Target.Value = userSelectedDate
    End If
    
End Sub
```